# doxygen 1.8.5 generates invalid index.hhc file

Tags: doxygen

I'm migrating our documentation project from CentOS 5 with Doxygen 1.6.1 to CentOS 7 with Doxygen 1.8.5

The new doxygen version keeps generating index.hhc files (which are intended to be fed to hhc.exe on Windows) which refer to non-existing "axxxxx.html" files.

Is anyone aware of issues which could cause this?

Comment: Version 1.8.5 is from August 2013, what happens with the current 1.8.8 version? Furthermore can you give a minimal example (source file and Doxyfle) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to 1.8.8. CentOS 7 comes with 1.8.5 and there are no ready-made RPM's of 1.8.8. I'm trying to compile the rpm now (hitting problems).
I'm aware that it's best to provide a minimal example demonstrating the problem but the current input is huge and complex and I don't know Doxygen enough to concoct a smaller example. I'll try to do that.

Comment: What kind of problems do you have compiling? Normally ./configure followed by make would do.